# How does this derive?

Tags: complex-analysis

From https://math.berkeley.edu/~ceur/notes_pdf/Eur_ComplexAnalysis_Notes.pdf. exercise 1.8 excercise 1.B

How did they get from

\begin{align}
 |w − z|^2 ≤ |1 − \overline{w}z|^2
\end{align}
(keep in mind that the second w has a bar on top, as you can see from the link I've listed)

to

\begin{align}
|z|^2 + |w|^2 ≤ 1 + |w|^2|z|^2
\end{align}

I think this has something to do with the Euclidean norm. I spend two days trying to search how this is done. Now I require some input.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $|w| \le 1, |z| \le 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use $|z|^{2}=z\overline{z}$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$. For example, $|z-w|^{2}=(z-w)\overline{(z-w)}=|z|^{2}-z\overline{w}-\overline{z}w+|w|^{2}$.

Comment: I can't upvote, but thank you.